# Extract documentation strings from SQL Scripts

Tags: sql-server, documentation, documentation-generation

How can I best extract the documentation strings from T/SQL scripts and present them as a user-frienfly API documentation?  I know about tools like Doxygen, Javadocs or Sphinx, but none of them seem to know about SQL.

For example, I want to be able to make use of the documentation in scripts that contain create statements like follows:

```
/**
 * This is a stored procedure.
 *
 * @param foo foo does bar
 */
create procedure my_proc(foo varchar(100)
...
GO
```

Comment: I edited the question to make it more answerable as per e.g. [this Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288832/which-questions-about-programming-tools-are-allowed) and I think it can be reopened now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL Refactor tool together with the SQL Prompt tool from Red gate Might have what you are looking for.
[link](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-toolbelt/)
I have used it a long time ago to document my own Stored Procs

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for a free tool.

Comment: Sorry. I am unaware of a free tool that does this. However the tools mentioned above has free trails.

Answer (score 4):

You should try [Natural Docs](http://www.naturaldocs.org/) to document SQL-procedures. It is open-source, really straight forward and well documented. An example would look like

```
/**
 * This is a stored procedure.
 *
 * Parameters:
 *   foo - foo does bar
 */
create procedure my_proc(foo varchar(100)
...
GO
```

The output is generated as nice-looking HTML. You can specify custom sections for return-values, date and author, or include usage-guidelines and code samples in your output. Have fun!